# How to append a value from jquery to an html document

Tags: jquery

Hello folks and thanks in advance for reading this.
I currently use a slider image gallery that i really like but unfortunately doesnt give you the option of enlarging/zooming the selected photo. 
So i found another jquery script (called pretty photo) that does the trick.
The only issue is that the pretty photo script doesnt understand whats the current image selected and always shows the first photo of the group.
So i guess i have to grab the current photo value from the first script and append it to the href value that the preety photo script reads to enlarge the current photo.

My html code is

```
        <ul class="gallery clearfix">
        <li><a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]"   href="../images/large/<#OBJECT#>_<#CURRENT_IMAGE#>.jpg">
        <img  src="../images/medium/<#OBJECT#>_1.jpg"  />
                    </a></li>
        </ul>
                    </div>
```

The part of the jquery script that grabs the current photo value is..

```
    var x = parseInt($("#currentPhoto").text());
```

So i think i have to pass the  x value to my href link.
I hope i made myself clear.Any suggestions will be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("a[rel='prettyPhoto[gallery]'").attr({href:x});
```

This piece of code will set attr href to value X;

Or actually you just have the number, then we are to format it accordingly.

```
x = "../link/to/your/images/image_prefix_"+x+".ext";
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you mean `src` attribute:

```
 var x = $("#currentPhoto").attr('src');
 $("a").attr('href', x);
```